# Uso de basemap en python

Tags: python, basemap

Hola estoy intentando colocar las coordenadas de dos lugares en un mapa usando basemap, las coordenadas que estoy intentando colocar son de 20.41N, 158.21W, hasta 2.11S, 58.41W y unir estas dos puntos con una linea como se ve en esta figura:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi codigo es el siguiente

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np 
from datetime import datetime


fig = plt.figure()

map = Basemap(projection='mill', llcrnrlat=-90, urcrnrlat=90, llcrnrlon=-180, urcrnrlon=180, lon_0=180)
map.drawcoastlines()

map.drawparallels(np.arange(-90,90,30),labels=[1,0,0,0])
map.drawmeridians(np.arange(map.lonmin,map.lonmax+30,60),labels=[0,0,0,1])

map.scatter(37.41,-90, latlon= True, s= 40, marker ='^', c ='blue')
map.scatter(-62.1,-58.4, latlon= True, s= 40, marker ='s', c ='red')

date = datetime(2007, 9, 1, hour=0, minute=0, second=0)

CS=map.nightshade(date)
plt.title('Day/Night Map for %s (UTC)' % date.strftime("%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S"))

plt.show()
```

Comment: Unirlos cómo? Línea recta? Curva de menor distancia?

Comment: como se ve en la figura

Comment: En la figura hay una curva, pero no me alcanza para saber qué método querés elegir para unir los puntos. Fijate si es esto lo que querés: https://matplotlib.org/basemap/api/basemap_api.html#mpl_toolkits.basemap.Basemap.drawgreatcircle

Comment: claro drawgreatcircle me pareceria

Comment: pero las coordenadas no me cuadran en la imagen